# Issue while getting rtsp streams on aws ec2 instance

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, rtsp

I want to display 2 rtsp camera streams simantaniously on a page .I can successfully streams these camera on my localhost but unable to get these streams on aws ec2 instance.I also enable 2000 port on aws scurity groups.Streams binary git stuck on :

00000000: 6a73 6d70 0000 0000                      jsmp....

here is my react code:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { loadPlayer } from "rtsp-relay/browser";

const App = () => {
  const canvasRefs = useRef([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const streamUrls = [
      "ws://localhost:2000/api/stream/0",
      "ws://localhost:2000/api/stream/1",
      "ws://localhost:2000/api/stream/2",
      "ws://localhost:2000/api/stream/3",
    ];

    streamUrls.forEach((url, index) => {
      const playerOptions = {
        url,
        canvas: canvasRefs.current[index],
        autoplay: true,
        video: true,
      };
      loadPlayer(playerOptions);
    });
  }, []);

  const numCanvases = 4; // Set the desired number of canvas elements

  // Generate the array of canvas elements
  const canvases = Array.from({ length: numCanvases }, (_, index) => (
    <canvas
      key={`canvas-${index}`}
      id={`canvas-${index}`}
      ref={(el) => (canvasRefs.current[index] = el)}
      style={{ height: "400px", width: "400px", objectFit: "contain" }}
    ></canvas>
  ));

  return <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>{canvases}</div>;
};

export default App;
```

and here is code in express js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");

const { proxy, scriptUrl } = require("rtsp-relay")(app);

const urls = [
  "rtsp://admin:senti4512@sentinel.nayatel.net:554/chID=1&streamType=main",
  "rtsp://admin:senti4512@sentinel.nayatel.net:554/chID=2&streamType=main",
  "rtsp://admin:senti4512@sentinel.nayatel.net:554/chID=1&streamType=main",
  "rtsp://admin:senti4512@sentinel.nayatel.net:554/chID=2&streamType=main",
];

let i = 0;
for (const url of urls) {
  const handler = proxy({
    url: url,
    verbose: false,
    transport: "tcp",
  });

  app.ws("/api/stream/" + i, handler);
  i++;
}

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));
app.get("/*", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client/build", "index.html"));
});

app.listen(2000, () => {
  console.log("Express server listening on port 2000");
});
```

I also tried to these two veriosn to get streams

```
useEffect(() => {const streamers = ['ws://server-ip:2000/api/stream/0','ws://server-ip:2000/api/stream/1',
```

```
];
```

```
anduseEffect(() => {const streamers = ['ws://server-ip/api/stream/0','ws://server-ip/api/stream/1',
```

```
];
```